# How to create a "search" field in xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, custom-controls

How to create a "search" field in xamarin?  As in the annex. I mean mainly the border.

I am trying to make a custom but I have only the bottom line for now

```
    assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomSearch), typeof(CustomSearchRenderer))]
namespace Sparking.Droid.CustomRenderers
{
    public class CustomSearchRenderer : EntryRenderer
     {
        public CustomSearchRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            var view = (CustomSearch)Element;
            if (view == null) return;

            Control.SetPadding((int)view.Padding.Left, (int)view.Padding.Top,
                (int)view.Padding.Right, (int)view.Padding.Bottom);

            Control.Background.SetColorFilter(view.UnderlineUnFocusColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcAtop);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a `SearchBar` view in Xamrain.Forms (see [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.SearchBar/)).

Just add it in your XAML

```
<SearchBar Text="{Binding SearchText}" 
           SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}" 
           Placeholder="Search" />
```

no need to create a custom `EntryRenderer` for that.

Comment: but SearchBar is not supported in android 7.0

Comment: and I need add icon

Comment: There is a  bug with the SearchBar in Nougat, but there is a workaround ([see here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/79446/is-there-support-for-searchbar-on-nougat-7-0)).